# Checking the format of a string in Matlab

Tags: matlab

So I'm reading multiple text files in Matlab that have, in their first columns, a column of "times". These times are either in the format 'MM:SS.milliseconds' (sorry if that's not the proper way to express it) where for example the string '29:59.9' would be (29*60)+(59)+(.9) = 1799.9 seconds, or in the format of straight seconds.milliseconds, where '29.9' would mean 29.9 seconds. The format is the same for a single file, but varies across different files. Since I would like the times to be in the second format, I would like to check if the format of the strings match the first format. If it doesn't match, then convert it, otherwise, continue. The code below is my code to convert, so my question is how do I approach checking the format of the string? In otherwords, I need some condition for an if statement to check if the format is wrong.

```
 %% Modify the textdata to convert time to seconds
    timearray = textdata(2:end, 1);
    if (timearray(1, 1) %{has format 'MM.SS.millisecond}%)
        datev = datevec(timearray);
        newtime = (datev(:, 5)*60) + (datev(:, 6));

    elseif(timearray(1, 1) %{has format 'SS.millisecond}%)
        newtime = timearray;
```

Comment: Consider using regular expressions to check when a number follows a particular format.  I'll write an answer for you

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll check out regexp

Comment: You're very welcome.  I wrote an answer for you.  Good luck!

Comment: a little trick I used some time: pretend minutes `MM` are seconds `SS` and remove the dot so you could make `SS.millisecond` to `FFF`. So you finally have `SS:FFF` which is a format Matlab can recognize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to help you out.  Regular expressions are methods of specifying how to search for particular patterns in strings.  As such, you want to find if a string follows the formats of either:

```
xx:xx.x
```

or:

```
xx.x
```

The regular expression syntax for each of these is defined as the following:

1. `^[0-9]+:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`
2. `^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`

Let's step through how each of these work.

- For the first one, the `^[0-9]+` means that the string should **start** with any number (`^[0-9]`) and the `+` means that there should be **at least one number**.  As such, 1, 2, ... 10, ... 20, ... etc. is valid syntax for this beginning.  After the number should be separated by a `:`, followed by another sequence of numbers of at least one or more.  After, there is a `.` that separates them, then this is followed by another sequence of numbers.  Notice how I used `\.` to specify the `.` character.  Using `.` by itself means that the character is a **wildcard**.  This is obviously not what you want, so if you want to specify the actual `.` character, you need to prepend a `\` to the `.`.
- For the second one, it's almost the same as the first one.  However, there is no `:` delimiter, and we only have the `.` to work with.

To invoke regular expressions, use the [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) command in MATLAB.  It is done using:

```
ind = regexp(str, expression);
```

`str` represents the string you want to check, and expression is a regular expression that we talked about above.  You need to make sure you encapsulate your expression using single quotes.  The regular expression is taken in as a string.  `ind` would this return the starting index of your string of where the match was found.  As such, when we search for a particular format, `ind` should either be **1** indicating that we found this search **at the beginning** of the string, or it returns **empty** (`[]`) if it didn't find a match.  Here's a reproducible example for you:

```
B = {'29:59.9', '29.9', '45:56.8', '24.5'};

for k = 1 : numel(B)
    if (regexp(B{k}, '^[0-9]+:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+') == 1)
        disp('I''m the first case!');
    elseif (regexp(B{k}, '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+') == 1) 
        disp('I''m the second case!');
    end
end
```

As such, the code should print out `I'm the first case!` if it follows the format of the first case, and it should print `I'm the second case!` if it follows the format of the second case.  As such, by running this code, we get:

```
I'm the first case!
I'm the second case!
I'm the first case!
I'm the second case!
```

Without knowing how your strings are formatted, I can't do the rest of it for you, but this should be a good start for you.