# How to restrict input string in length,symbols, char and numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am developing an app where the user inputs a string which need several restrictions. How can I check that the input is in the format 'LLL-NN-NNN' where L is lettes (A-Z) and N is numbers (0-9), and the string have to be exactly 10 characters in total.

Comment: using a regular expression.

Comment: @SardarUsama ok, Can you show me an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24741003/

Comment: @SardarUsama perfect, thanks I will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

```
if ~isempty(regexp(your_string, '^[A-Z]{3}-\d{2}-\d{3}$', 'match', 'once'))
    % your code
end
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how it works to make it more useful for the beginners and future visitors